Need Advice on Using Certbot with Nginx for SSL Certificates
I need some advice on how to properly use Certbot to obtain SSL certificates from Let's Encrypt. For context, I am doing this in a script, so I need it to be non-interactive.
I have a basic configuration file for a web service:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.tld;
    root /var/www/super_site/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

Then I run Certbot to get the certificates:
sudo certbot --nginx --agree-tos --redirect --hsts --staple-ocsp --email email@provider.tld -d domain.tld -d www.domain.tld

Certbot does the job and returns:
Congratulations! You have successfully enabled HTTPS on https://....

Everything works, but when I look at the configuration file in /etc/nginx/conf.d it’s not very neat.
        server {
        server_name domain.tld;
        root /var/www/super_site/public/;
        index index.php index.html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_error.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

}            server {
    if ($host = domain.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.tld;
        root /var/www/super_site/public/;
        index index.php index.html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_error.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

}

Certbot is helpful here:
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

Because, in some ways, I’m still learning, and it shows me how to configure SSL.
When I look at the documentation , I think  I should use the 'certonly' option? And write the configuration file myself.
sudo certbot certonly -n --nginx --agree-tos --redirect --hsts --staple-ocsp --email email@provider.tld -d domain.tld www.domain.tld

The configuration file could look like this:
    server {

    if ($host = domain.tld) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; 
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name domain.tld;
    root /var/www/super_site/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/super_site_error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/chain.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

Is using the 'certonly' option what I need? Or did I miss something else? I know I have to improve my knowledge. Thank you for your time and help.

I recommend using default nginx configuration, then using certbot. If you compare the default nginx config with the config, modified by certbot, you'll learn how to write a config by yourself. Also take a look in the documentation.

I use --certonly always here, as the way Certbot does the configuration is not optimal.
I recommend also having a separate block for HTTP, like shown in Redirect all requests to HTTPS, except for one subdirectory
That way you make sure that no users visit the site via HTTP, and there won´t be any content considered duplicate by search engines.
